# trouble shooting a speed bottleneck in a program with sql queries

Tags: sql

This is an open ended interview question. I am not able to get a satisfactory answer.
The question is:

If you were trying to fix a speed bug involving a feature that took 90 seconds to execute when the customer expected the feature to take less than 10 seconds, how would you approach the problem and solve it?  Assume the feature had 10 queries, 30 calculations, and 3000 lines of code spread over 5 modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first part of the answer is that you would use a profiler in whatever the code language is to first verify that the bottleneck is in the SQL queries and not in some processing.  The profiler will also be able to tell you which queries are taking the most time by telling you the amount of time spent in each method.  Once you got that, you can use a database query optimizer to fix the queries if that is the problem.

Comment: +1 Profile, profile, profile.  As a software *engineer*, you need data before you can really approach a solution to anything.

Comment: i guess when it says that instead of 10secs it is taking 90 seconds, that means something has really went wrong. Can it also be because the customer has a small computer memory.

Comment: I guess that does bring up the next part of the answer would be that if you don't find any obvious problems that maybe the customer's expectations were incorrect given the constraints of the problem or the system.

Answer (score 1):

Too open ended, but there's a few things you can try:

- Make sure you understand the customer's requirements correctly
- Make sure you understand where the performance bottleneck is in your current setup
- Make sure that the right indexes exist for the queries you have in
  mind
- Optimize the DB schema, de-normalize where necessary to avoid joins
- Explore caching and pre-computing results where applicable as an option so you don't have to query the DB in the first place.
- If all technical avenues are explored or time and effort would be too much, reset expectations with the customer if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

humm...I would try to isolate each of the "steps" and see how long each of them are taking to execute. I would focus on the SQLs first by running a trace with profiler because they usually take longer to run. Once I have the values I would decide the next step. I cant tell that i would focus 100% on database if I see that Db is only responsible for 10% of the exec time for example